# Pressure variance with height of the atmosphere-conflict of answers

Tags: atmospheric-science

When we use the standard equations pertaining to the International Standard Atmosphere to calculate the pressure at 25km above sea level, the answer seems way off from the values that we get over the internet. Why so?
The equation in wikipedia reads:[image]

Therefore from 11km to 25km the atmomsphere is isothermal hence we use the second equation. The pressure at 11km is 22700 Pa , h= 25, h_b =11 and T_b = 216.66

The answer I get from this calculation is 22577 Pa and the answer that most calculators over the net show is ten times lower-2549 Pa
did I assume anything wrong? Or was it simply a calculation error somewhere?

Comment: Show your working in detail, then we may be able to see if it was your error.

Comment: @SolarMike Haven't I given the working, as in the values of the variables I took and the equation I used?

Comment: No, you showed the original equations and the values you assumed... But not the detail where you might have made the error.

Comment: Ok ..so when I Google up the atmospheric variation of temperature the band between 11 to 25 km is an isothermal layer. Therefore as per wiki's formula we have to consider the second formula. The pressure at 11 km has to considered when applying the formula..(wiki's Def) even that I googled up and the base temperature at 11km is also available over the net

Comment: Using these stuff..I arrive at an alternate answer altogether